# Upgrading a Mathematica 5 package to version 9

Tags: cryptography, wolfram-mathematica, aes

I have been trying to get a package from
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5130/
(an MMA implementation of AES) to work in version 9. There is something about loading the Finite fields package that doesn't seem to make sense (eg, I can load FiniteFields separately and <<"AES`" still complains, specifically about Algebra`FiniteFields.
I have installed the AES.m package in 
C:\Program Files\WolframResearch\Mathematica\9.0\AddOns\ExtraPackages\AES.
and everthing indicates that it is ok. (viewing, running the package)

I think that I am missing something basic, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Try your question on the appropriate site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line in the package to:

```
 BeginPackage["Cryptography`AES`", "FiniteFields`"];
```

Comment: Results in the following message: BeginPackage::cxt: Invalid context specified at position 1 in      BeginPackage[CryptographyAES,FiniteFields`]. A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with `. >>

Comment: @stuartw thanks, it didn't come out until I changed it to 'code',